# Reset email send me example.com url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

When I try to use the password password/reset send me a mail with this this url

http://example.com/password-reset/confirm/MjM/572-52a21bbd1b80e9377f98/                 Any ideas??

```
settings.py


SITE_ID = 1
#Registro simple sin correo
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

#Login no mail
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = 
reverse_lazy('account_confirm_complete')
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = 
reverse_lazy('account_confirm_complete')
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
#Following is added to enable registration with email instead of username
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
 # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
 "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",

 # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
 "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)
```

Comment: You're uising SITE_ID = 1.  Go into admin and change the Domain name etc for the site

Comment: yes. 
I update my comment to add part of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will obviously happen if you use **`SITE_ID=1`** in your settings. The ***django-all-auth*** package uses the value of ***`domain`*** field of ***`SITE_ID`*** while creating a ***reset-password mail***.
So, you can do either,

#### 1. Change the value of `domain` of existing **`SITE_ID`**

Run the script in your **Django Shell**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

site = Site.objects.get(id=settings.SITE_ID)
site.domain = "your.required.domain.com"
site.name = "Some Readable Name for Your Site"
site.save()
```

#### 2. Create new **`Site`** instance and put newly created site id in `settings.py`

Run this on django shell,

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

site = Site.objects.create(domain="your.required.domain.com", name="Some Readable Name for Your Site")
print(site.id)
```

Now, you'll get the new ***site id***, put that in settings.py as,

```
#settings.py
SITE_ID = 123 # here "123" is the id of your newly creted site object
```

---

#### Note

These things(**1** and **2**) can also be done via Django Admin console.